# SQL Server query error for T-SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm getting a my error message as I try to execute the code...

The variable `x` is working properly and showing expected values so are the `textBoxes`. And connection is open and working as wel because code block before it works fine!

```
string x = ViaClass.name;

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(); 
connection.ConnectionString = (@"myconString;Integrated Security=YES");
command.Connection = connection;

try
{
    connection.Open();

    command.CommandText = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ADDRESSES WHERE USID =" + "'" + x + "'" +")" + " INSERT INTO ADDRESSES " + "(AddressLine1, AddressLine2, PostCode) VALUES " + " (@AddressLine1, @AddressLine2, @PostCode)";

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressLine1", addressLine1TextBox.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddressLine2", addressLine2TextBox.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostCode", postCodeTextBox.Text);


    int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (result > 0) MessageBox.Show("Record successfully added!");
    else MessageBox.Show("Failed to add record!");
}
catch (SqlException ex) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my SQL? I'm using SQL Server and C#

Screenshot for first sql

[image]

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @AndrewBarber `Failed to add record!` as I have defined it in `Try` `Catch`

Comment: Have you run your queries individually? Maybe the first one isn't returning what you expect.

Comment: Not that it is the cause of the error, but you should use a `SqlParameter` for `USID`/`x` like you do for other parameterized values in your query.

Comment: I think its the sql
`command.CommandText =`

Comment: @J0e3gan ellaborate/code please?

Comment: @AndrewBarber check the screenshot please

Comment: `command.CommandText = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ADDRESSES WHERE USID = @USID)" + " INSERT INTO ADDRESSES " + "(AddressLine1, AddressLine2, PostCode) VALUES " + " (@AddressLine1, @AddressLine2, @PostCode)";`

`command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USID", x);`

`/* Continue with other command.Parameters.AddWithValue calls. */`

Comment: We can see the query; I asked if you had run them  individually. Run the `SELECT` query first to make sure it returns what you think it should.

Answer (score 1):

If the statement:

```
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ADDRESSES WHERE USID =" + "'" + x + "'" +")
```

Is false, then

```
 result = 0
```

Does your data already exist in the database?

---

For a valid statement for this verification do

```
 command.CommandText = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ADDRESSES WHERE USID =" + "'" + x + "'" +")" + " INSERT INTO ADDRESSES " + "(AddressLine1, AddressLine2, PostCode) VALUES " + " (@AddressLine1, @AddressLine2, @PostCode) ELSE SELECT 1";
```

But I don't think that having an 'IF' before your update and the checking affect number of rows is a good way for checking if your operation was successful.

Comment: I just want to add a new row where USID = 'x'

Comment: If there's a better way to go about this then please enlighten me :)

Comment: Is this a multi user system? Are they likely to update the same record at once? If not, you could use a select statement to check if the parameter is already inserted. And skip the update. Else, you could just try to insert the record without the tsql if.. then your `if(result > 0)` should be ok. If something goes wrong, you might get an Exception.